# How to remove/clear content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created simple webpage(not master or content page),I am taking value from user in the form of querystring.
In web page after taking value in the form of querystring ,inserting into table and returning id to user.It is working properly.But when after returning id to user,I am viewing source code,able to see 1 along with all html tag.I don't want all html tag,want only plain 1.How to do that?I already used these methods Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

Comment: It's hard to imagine and understand your issue without screen shot of source code view as you mentioned. Can you provide some screen shot to explain that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using webforms? Webforms is designed to return a full html page on every request and you shouldn't mix Response.Write (which I guess you are using) with regular form processing. This is because you can't control where the output of Response.Write will end up in the rest of the markup.

That said, when you really want to use just Response.Write and ignore the form output, use [Response.CompleteRequest()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) to signal that the response is done and further processing can be skipped.

Or if you want to spend more time, look into WebAPI. That is designed for these "simple return value" situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely control output, you can do something like this:

```
byte[] arrBytes = { (byte)'t', (byte)'e', (byte)'s', (byte)'t' };
try
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline");
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.OutputStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    throw new ApplicationException("Error writing RAW data", ex);
}
Response.End();
```

This code is a bit long, but it is complete and should work.  When called in an *.aspx page (or *.ascx control) this code will output a document with only the word "test" in it and absolutely nothing else.